# PHP Give up link and show number link

Tags: php

I am stuck on two parts for this. I need a give Up link that displays the generated number for the current game. Also include a Start Over link that deletes the user session and uses the header(“location: URL”) function to navigate to the main page. 
Here is my code for the game so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><form "action="game.php" method="POST">
Guess a number 1-100:<input type="text" name="userGuess"/>
<input type="submit" value="Guess"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['randNum'] = isset($_SESSION['randNum']) ? $_SESSION['randNum'] : rand(0, 100);
$_SESSION['guesses'] = isset($_SESSION['guesses']) ? $_SESSION['guesses'] : 0;

$randNum = $_SESSION['randNum'];
$userGuess = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userGuess");


if (isset($randNum)) {
    if ($userGuess<$randNum) {
            echo "<center>You guessed too low!</center>";
            $_SESSION['guesses']++;
            echo $_SESSION['guesses'];
        }
    if ($userGuess>$randNum) {
            echo "<center>You guessed too high!</center>";
            $_SESSION['guesses']++;
            echo $_SESSION['guesses'];
        }
    if ($userGuess==$randNum) {
            echo "<center>Congratulations You're right!!!</center>";
                         unset($_SESSION["randNum"], $_SESSION['guesses']);
    }
    if ($userGuess>100 || $userGuess<0) {
            echo "<center>Please enter a number betweeen 1 and 100!</center>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Please enter a number between 1 and 100";
}
?>
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. your code is a little messy. please fix the indentation, which will make it easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code with a few tweaks/corrections:

1. `<form "action="game.php">` to `<form action="game.php">`
2. Closed `<center>` tag.
3. PHP has got to go before sending/printing out anything due to the presence of the header function.
4. The messages should be displayed in the `<body>` tag.
5. Cutoff for `$userGuess` should be less than `1`, not `0`.
6. Changed the structure of the `if/else` statements to reduce clutter.
7. Changed `<input type="text">` to `<input type="number">`.

   ```
   <?php

   session_start();

   $_SESSION['randNum'] = isset($_SESSION['randNum']) ? $_SESSION['randNum'] : rand(0, 100);
   $_SESSION['guesses'] = isset($_SESSION['guesses']) ? $_SESSION['guesses'] : 0;

   $randNum = $_SESSION['randNum'];

   if (isset($_POST['userGuess'])) {

       $userGuess = $_POST['userGuess'];

       if ($userGuess > 100 || $userGuess < 1) {

           $message = "Please enter a number betweeen 1 and 100!";

       } else {

           if ($userGuess < $randNum) {

                   $message = "You guessed too low!";
                   $count = $_SESSION['guesses'];
                   $_SESSION['guesses']++;

               } elseif ($userGuess>$randNum) {

                   $message = "You guessed too high!";
                   $count = $_SESSION['guesses'];
                   $_SESSION['guesses']++;

               } else {

                   $message = "Congratulations You're right!!!";
                   session_unset();

           }

       }

   }

   if (isset($_GET['giveup'])) {

       $message = "The answer was " . $randNum . ". I picked a new number to play again.";
       $_SESSION['randNum'] = rand(0, 100);
       $_SESSION['guesses'] = 0;

   } else if (isset($_GET['restart'])) {

       session_unset();
       header("location: game.php");
       exit();

   }

   ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Guessing Game</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <center>

   <?php

   echo (isset($message) ? ($message . '<br />') : false) . (isset($count) ? ($count . '<br />') : false);

   ?>

   <form action="game.php" method="POST">
   Guess a number 1-100:
   <input type="number" name="userGuess" />
   <input type="submit" value="Guess" />
   </form>

   <a href="game.php?giveup">Give up</a>
   <a href="game.php?restart">Start over</a>

   </center>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Comment: Awesome, I ended up doing something like that but with 3 different files. One thing I have noticed with your coding and mine, is that the session starts with the guess counter already at 1, any idea why?

Comment: It appears I made the mistake of increasing the counter before printing it out. I managed to fix it by changing the order of `$count` definition and `$_SESSION['guesses']++` inside the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tweaks, but basically is just adding a couple of buttons to the form and a bit of field handling on the server side:

```
<?php
session_start();

function resetGame() {
    unset($_SESSION["randNum"], $_SESSION['guesses']);
}
function restart() {
    header("location: game.php");
}

$_SESSION['randNum'] = isset($_SESSION['randNum']) ? $_SESSION['randNum'] : rand(0, 100);
$_SESSION['guesses'] = isset($_SESSION['guesses']) ? $_SESSION['guesses'] : 0;
$giveUp = isset($_POST['give-up']);
$solution = isset($_POST['solution']);

$randNum = $_SESSION['randNum'];
$userGuess = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userGuess");

if ($giveUp) {
    resetGame();
    restart();
} else if ($solution) {
   echo "The solution was ". $randNum ."!!";
   resetGame();
} else if (isset($randNum) && !is_null($userGuess)) {
    if ($userGuess<$randNum) {
        echo "<center>You guessed too low!</center>";
        $_SESSION['guesses']++;
        echo $_SESSION['guesses'];
    }      
    if ($userGuess>$randNum) {
        echo "<center>You guessed too high!</center>";
        $_SESSION['guesses']++;
        echo $_SESSION['guesses'];
    }
    if ($userGuess==$randNum) {
        echo "<center>Congratulations You're right!!!</center>";
        resetGame();
    }
    if ($userGuess>100 || $userGuess<0) {
        echo "<center>Please enter a number betweeen 1 and 100!</center>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Please enter a number between 1 and 100";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><form "action="game.php" method="POST">
Guess a number 1-100:<input type="text" name="userGuess"/>
<input type="submit" value="Guess"/>
<input type="submit" id="give-up" name="give-up" value="Give up"/>
<input type="submit" id="solution" name="solution" value="Show Solution"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```